# Ubuntu 16.04 slow performance

Tags: 16.04, ssd, performance, swap

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Inspiron 5547 i7-4510U on SSD. While everything works fine on other laptops, this one is really slow. It takes around 15 seconds to lock screen, Firefox is slower than internet explorer, delayed mouse clicks, delayed actions, it takes 2 seconds to switch tab in Firefox, etc. I have no idea what's the problem, I couldn't find any drivers that could help, edited `/etc/sysctl.conf` :

```
vm.swappiness=10
vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
```

but that doesn't work like i'd like to.
I did clean install and it's still the same.

Comment: What's the output of `free -h` and `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA`? Did you ever run a performance test on the SSD in case this particular one doesn't work well (hardware failure or bad system configuration)? A look into the output of `sudo dmesg` might also reveal oddities. Start looking from back to front.

Comment: @DavidFoerster
free -h output:
            `total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available`  
`Mem:           7,7G        3,1G        1,9G        680M        2,7G        3,6G`  
`Swap:          7,9G        109M        7,8G`  
lspci output:    
`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)
 Subsystem: Dell Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [1028:0640]
 Kernel driver in use: i915`    

I don't see anything wrong in dmesg. And sorry for such messy comment, formatting didn't work.

Comment: I can't read that. Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: while at least one CPU is fully loaded, what do you get for `grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo` ?

Comment: alright, i found the soulution - i had to turn on "Intel SpeedStep" in BIOS. Thanks for trying to help.